# Loops and subroutines

Tags: programming, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

I am new to *Mathematica* and not familiar with functional programming. In particular, I have no idea on how to replace the usual `for` loops in C++. Here is an example of the way I am writing code now:

```
InitCoords[] := {
  VDiv[gap, region, initCell];
  n = 0;
  For[nz = 0, nz < initCell[3], nz++,
   For [ny = 0, ny < initCell[2], ny++,
     For[nx = 0, nx < initCell[1], nx++,
       VSet[c, nx + 0.25, ny + 0.25, nz + 0.25];
       VMul[c, c, gap];
       VSAdd[c, c, -0.5, region];
       For[j = 0, j < 4, j++, 
        Do[r[n][i] = c[i], {i, 1, NDIM}];
        If[j != 3,
         If[j != 0, r[n][1] += 0.5*gap[1];];
         If[j != 1, r[n][2] += 0.5*gap[2];];
         If[j != 2, r[n][3] += 0.5*gap[3];];
         ];
       ++ n;
        ];
       ];
     ];
   ];
  }
```

I know that this is a very bad way to code in *Mathematica*. What are the alternatives then?

Another question. Is there is a *Mathematica* convention for defining a subroutine with no input? I want to partition my big program into smaller parts. Currently, I am doing it by writing a function with no input.

Comment: What do `VDiv`, `VSet`, `VMul`, and `VSAdd` do?

Comment: My own defined functions:
    VDiv[v1_, v2_, v3_] := {
      v1[1] = v2[1]/v3[1];
      v1[2] = v2[2]/v3[2];
      v1[3] = v2[3]/v3[3];
      }
Others are just similar like addition and multiplication. Now I just learn to use the list function to replace all those functions.

Comment: If you give the definitions of all functions used we can try to write a simpler version for you to illustrate.

Comment: VDiv[v1_, v2_, v3_] := {
      v1[1] = v2[1]/v3[1];
      v1[2] = v2[2]/v3[2];
      v1[3] = v2[3]/v3[3];
      }

VSet[v_, sx_, sy_, sz_] := {
  v[1] = sx; v[2] = sy; v[3] = sz;
  }

VMul[v1_, v2_, v3_] := {
  v1[1] = v2[1]*v3[1];
  v1[2] = v2[2]*v3[2];
  v1[3] = v2[3]*v3[3];
  }

VSAdd[v1_, v2_, s3_, v3_] := {
  v1[1] = v2[1] + s3*v3[1];
  v1[2] = v2[2] + s3*v3[2];
  v1[3] = v2[3] + s3*v3[3];
  }

(sorry it seems that I don't know the comment formatting)

Comment: Like C++, in _Mathematica_ there is really no distinction between functions and subroutines, so using functions with not arguments to organize your program is fine.

Comment: You should invest some time reading the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ListsOverview.html) about lists. Be aware that the notation is rather different from C. It looks like you are using `DownValues` (like `c[i]`) and `SubValues` (like `r[n][1]`) to mimic the array notation in C, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can make no argument functions in mathematica, for example:

```
f[] := Plot[x^2 - 1, {x, -2, 2}]
```

This function will always make the same plot, whenever

```
f[]
```

is called.

To make a real C/C++ function (in the meaning of logically encapsulated piece of code) jus use [Module[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) function. For example, the function that takes no arguments, makes a plot, and prints a few lines can be written as follows:

```
f[] := Module[
               {i}, (* variables to be treated as f[]'s local variables *)
```

`Do[Print["Line" + Text[i]], {i, 1, 5}] (*loop for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) std::cout<<"Line "<<IntToStr(i)<<std::endl; *)

           Plot[x^2 - 1, {x, -2, 2}] (* make also a plot *)

        ]  (* bracket ending the Module[] *)`

Hope that helped a little :]

PS.: Don't ever give up C/C++ programming. It will become useful in future to combine faster functions with mathematica.

PS.: Also take a look at [Compile[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html)

Comment: Thanks! Then is the Do loop more efficient than For loop?